# Java and process name

Tags: debian, java, process

I'm working on a daemon written in Java. I want to figure out a way I can still run /usr/bin/java but when using top/ps it shows a different name. I've tried creating a hardlink and a symbolic link to java and calling the link instead of java itself but no such luck.

I wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible to do this but I figured I'd see if any gurus on here knew. The distribution is Debian 5. The reason I want to do this is so it's easier to figure out which process is related to the daemon without checking the pid file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the "different name" it is showing?

Comment: It's showing "java" which obviously makes sense since java is running. I'm just hoping that "maybe" there is a way to mask it by symlinks or something similar so it shows a different app name.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882826/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-java-application-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash % exec -a "myprogram" java myprogram

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using start-stop-daemon. I'm accepting your answer since I wasn't specific.